# Django split the word and stored in database table

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a models with name keyskills. In this table i want to split keyskills by comma and stored it in one by one. Example

```
userinput for keyskills = "django,python,html"

in database table(employerkeyskills)

id  |  emp_id  |  job_id  |  keyskills
----|----------|----------|------------
1   |    2     |     1    |   django
2   |    2     |     1    |   python
3   |    2     |     1    |   html
```

*models.py*

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class jobs(models.Model):
    emp = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    referencecode = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    jobsummary = models.TextField()
    jobdetails = models.TextField()

class employerkeyskills(models.Model):
    emp=models.ForeignKey(User,unique=False)
    job=models.ForeignKey(jobs,unique=False)
    keyskills=models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

here i want to split keyskills by comma(,) which get from user input and stored it ONE BY ONE IN EMPLOYERKEYSKILLS table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for skill in keyskills.split(','):
  employerkeyskills.objects.create(emp=..., job=..., keyskills=skill)
```